# R shinyapp selecting pre-stored data set from checkbox

Tags: r, visualization, shiny, shiny-server

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput("data", "Select data:",
                       c("Iris" = "iris",
                         "Cars" = "mtcars")),
    plotOutput("myPlot")
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
      plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data = input$data)
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have a shinyApp where I want the user to select a data set. From there, I want to use that data set to make a simple plot. However, it seems that the user input into the checkbox didn't pass in successfully to the `server`. How can I get around this?

Comment: your `input$data` would return a character vector `"iris"`, not the dataset `iris`. In your plotting function, change to this `data = data(input$data)`, which will load that specified data set

Comment: @waterling thanks for the quick response. Yes, I noticed that as well. Unfortunately your suggestion did not work. I get the same error: 'invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'

Comment: hm ok. try `get(input$data)`. That works for me.  `output$myPlot <- renderPlot({ if(is.null(input$data)) {return()} 
      plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data = get(input$data))
    })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to do this in shiny is with `switch()`, which means you don't need to specify the dataset in your input, you can do it all in the server. In your context:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("data", "Select data:",
                     c("Iris" = "iris",
                       "Cars" = "mtcars")),
  plotOutput("myPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dat <- reactive({
    switch()
  })
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
    dat <- switch(input$data, 
                  "iris" = iris,
                  "mtcars" = mtcars)
    plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data = get(input$data))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that you could use any strings in the `checkboxGroupInput`, which makes this a more flexible way to work.